# Jquery - Dynamically load html and script code

Tags: jquery

How can I dynamically load the following HTML/JS into the DOM:

```
    <div id="googleDFP" class="googleDFPAD">
        <script>googletag.cmd.push(function() {googletag.display('googleDFP');});</script>
    </div>
```

I've no issues appending some HTML to the DOM but I'm unsure how I can also append the script into the DIV.

I want to append this to a DIV called:

```
<div id="bannerDIV"></div>
```

The following doesn't work:

```
$('#bannerDIV').append('<div id="googleDFP" class="googleDFPAD"><script>googletag.cmd.push(function() {googletag.display('googleDFP');});</script></div>');
```

Note: I need the script to be active once loaded.

thanks for any ideas :)

Comment: You have quotes that aren't escaped around 'googleDFP'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of a syntax error. You should be careful about what quotes you have in append text. 
Try following:

```
$('#bannerDIV').append('<div id="googleDFP" class="googleDFPAD"> <script>googletag.cmd.push(function() {googletag.display(\'googleDFP\');});</script></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a (vanilla javascript) function that creates the `div` and the `script` elements like :

```
function googleDFP(divTarget) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute("id", "googleDFP");
    div.setAttribute("class", "googleDFPAD");
    var myScript = document.createElement('script');
    myScript.innerHTML = "googletag.cmd.push(function() {googletag.display('googleDFP');});";
    document.getElementById(divTarget).appendChild(div);
    document.getElementById("googleDFP").appendChild(myScript);
}
```

This *function* accepts the target *div* `ID` as argument. Then call that *function* any time you want to append those elements to any other element passing the ID of the target element like

```
googleDFP("bannerDIV");
```